# How to Trigger an event with keys(ctrl +)(jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

How can I trigger an event with jQuery if I press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key plus the ++ key(zoom in).

key = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> ++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$(window).keypress(function(e){

   if((e.which == 61 && e.ctrlKey) || (e.which == 43 && e.ctrlKey)){
       //Ctrl + "+" is pressed, 61 is for =/+ anr 43 is for Numpad + key
   } 

});
```

Comment: Note: this does work on mac but the default mac zoom key combo is META+, not CTRL+ so this might not work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

An example of binding to `Ctrl+I`. Note that you can't override default browser behavior, so many of the `Ctrl+(letter)` shortcuts are reserved (Ctrl+T = new tab, Ctrl+N = new Window, Ctrl+P = Print etc...)

```
$(window).keydown(function(e){
  if(e.which == 17)
      $(window).bind('keydown.ctrlI', function(e){
          if(e.which == 73){
              e.preventDefault();
              alert('CTRL+I');
          }
      });
});

$(window).keyup(function(e){
  if(e.which == 17)
      $(window).unbind('keydown.ctrlI');
});
```

Comment: okay so i cant run an event when the browser zooms in? (CTRL plus +)

Comment: No, no, no.... use the `.ctrlKey` property of the event object to determine if the CTRL key is pressed...

Comment: @user759235 Oh, you meant the `+` literally. Sorry I interpreted it as `Ctrl` *plus* another key. I'll update my post in a second, I'm not sure if you can detect `Ctrl+` or not.

Comment: @user759235, nope it looks like you can't override the behavior of `Ctrl+` in Google Chrome at least. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
// the element at which you are firing the event
var div = $('#foo');

// the event handler
div.bind('paint', function() {
    $(this).addClass('painted');
});

$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    // if CTRL + + was pressed
    if ( e.ctrlKey && e.which === 187 ) {
        // trigger the event
        div.trigger('paint');
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/NMYJW/